# Can we run HTTPServlet in Main method Java Class

Tags: java, servlets

I am looking at an example code of Simple Servlet in Java.

In this example Servletis started by a WEB-INF/web.xml file entry

```
<servlet-class>com.mkyong.ServletDemo1</servlet-class>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet Name For Demo1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mkyong.ServletDemo1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet Name For Demo1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Demo1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can I start( com.mkyong.ServletDemo1) in a Java Application within main() method, calling a method. is it possible ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible. You can use Jetty, a lightweight Servlet container. It is possible to embed Jetty in your own application like that (this example is directly taken from the [Jetty documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedding-jetty.html#_embedding_servlets)):

```
public class MinimalServlets
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a basic jetty server object that will listen on port 8080.
        // Note that if you set this to port 0 then a randomly available port
        // will be assigned that you can either look in the logs for the port,
        // or programmatically obtain it for use in test cases.
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // The ServletHandler is a dead simple way to create a context handler
        // that is backed by an instance of a Servlet.
        // This handler then needs to be registered with the Server object.
        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        // Passing in the class for the Servlet allows jetty to instantiate an
        // instance of that Servlet and mount it on a given context path.

        // IMPORTANT:
        // This is a raw Servlet, not a Servlet that has been configured
        // through a web.xml @WebServlet annotation, or anything similar.
        handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");

        // Start things up!
        server.start();

        // The use of server.join() the will make the current thread join and
        // wait until the server is done executing.
        // See
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()
        server.join();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
                                                            IOException
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello from HelloServlet</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use HTTPServlet you'll need an application server like Tomcat. You cannot simply use main method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible!!

Below code you can execute to achieve to run `Servlet` in Main method of a Java Class

**MainClass.java**

```
import java.net.*;  
import java.io.*; 

    public class MainClass
    {  
        public static void main (String args[]) 
        { 
            String line;
            try 
            { 
                URL url = new URL( "http://localhost:8085/E/MyServlet?name=Ashok" ); 
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
                line = in.readLine(); 
                System.out.println( line ); 
                in.close(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

---

**MyServlet.java**

```
import java.io.*; 
import javax.servlet.http.*; 
import javax.servlet.*;    
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
        { 
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter(); 
            out.println ("Hello " + req.getParameter("name") + ", this is SpecialServlet!"); 
            out.close(); 
        }
    }
```

---

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>E</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Put `MyServlet.class` inside `WEB-INF` -> `classes` folder.

Then run the `MainClass.java`

**Output**

Hello Ashok this is SpecialServlet!